# Tracking Page Events and Goals Does`t Work Correctly

Tags: xconnect, jss

I am working on a mobile application (Sitecore 9.1, JSS React Native) with a couple of pages. A page event is assigned to each of the mobile application pages.
I have enabled [indexing anonymous contacts](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts.html) and I am sending back and forth all the cookies that I receive from the layout service endpoint.

When closing the application I call `abandonsession.aspx` pages as described  [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13071/hitting-the-layout-service-endpoint-is-not-recording-analytics) to flush the interaction(s) to xConnect and xDB

but when I open Experience Profile the only one interaction that I see is the page visit of `abandonsession.aspx`, no other page visits, no page events or goals.

(I am sending the cookies to the `abandonsession.aspx` as well)

Am I missing something?

How should I flush my contact data to xConnect and xDB?

I assume that assigning goals and page events with JSS is the same as in a normal case scenario. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Can you try using a web browser (incognito is recommended) to directly request one of the mobile app pages via Layout Service? Then browse to the abandonsession.aspx page.

Then check Experience Profile to ensure that the interaction/contact is displaying and the page event is triggered.

e.g. `http://my-react-native-host.com/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=[page path here]&sc_apikey=[jss api key here]`

This will verify that requests to Layout Service are being tracked properly and help eliminate something on the Sitecore side as a potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely this is an issue with Robot Detection. In React Native I assume you are unabvle to trigger [Visitor Identification](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-platform/en/robot-detection-overview.html#idp29325). You would either need to find a way to simulate that script in a mobile app, or potentially look at Universal Tracker as an alternative.