# Experience profile doesn't display number of contacts fully after rebuild xDB search index

Tags: solr, xconnect

I migrated xDB data from the Mongo database to xConnect collection databases successfully.

After that, I tried to rebuild xDB search index. The rebuild process finished successfully.

But I noticed that Experience Profile didn't display the number of contacts fully.

It showed 42912 results (contacts) but I checked in xConnect collection databases (shard0 and shard1) and I saw that there were over 1200 000 contacts in them.

[image]

[image]

I tried to change MaximumInteractionPeriod in sc.XConnect.Collection.Model.Plugins.xml from 30 to 3000 before rebuilding but it was not working.

Anyone to know what wrong with it?

Comment: Have you enabled indexing of anonymous contacts? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/13023/842

Comment: @grg : yes i have enabled it before rebuilding xDB search index

Answer (score 1):

Probably my answer is short but as it is said in Sitecore documentation, Experience Profile lets you monitor the behavior of contacts that have interacted with your company or with your website. So it means that the Experience Profile displays only contacts with any interactions. So, for example, if you add contacts by importing them diractly into contact list, they will not be appiared in Experience Profile, but will be represented in xDB.

Comment: I did a query in xconnect collection databases to get contacs that have interactions with my site, the result was over 1 million. So the experience profile showed a wrong result :((

Comment: @DuanLe How have you query them? Can you share your request query?

Comment: yes, it’s very simple.Using IN operator SQL, I get contact ids in contacts table (shard0, shard1 database) that also in interactions table. Is it ok?

Comment: One more note regarding a time period... Could you click "Filter" button and check the dates which are used for search. https://www.screencast.com/t/zdm3x53avM

Comment: yes, i tried to filter from 1/9/2015 to 1/9/2018 and still got the same result (42912 contacts) and these contacts have interactions that occurred within the past 30 days :((